# Use count() in CASE Expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count

I have the following data and I need help creating a case expression with a condition, When more than one PPaymentID exists per PaymentID then M is Y else false.

```
PaymentID   ProductID  PPaymentID
1456789     1398        4587934
3445738     1398        8754418 
3445738     1399        8754419
```

I would like to see something like

```
  PaymentID   ProductID  PPaymentID     M
    1456789     1398        4587934     N
    3445738     1398        8754418     Y
    3445738     1399        8754419     Y
```

Comment: How does `count` come into it?

Comment: You can use [`exists`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to check for another `PPaymentID` without getting an exact `count`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only care whether there *is* another row with the same `PaymentId` and a different `PPaymentId` there is no need to obtain a precise `count`. It is more efficient to just check if such a row `exists`:

```
select PaymentId, ProductId, PPaymentId,
  case when exists ( select 42 from YourTableOData as iYTOD
    where iYTOD.PaymentId = YTOD.PaymentId and iYTOD.PPaymentId != YTOD.PPaymentId )
    then 'Y'
    else 'N' end as M
  from YourTableOData as YTOD;
```

Comment: HABO what is 42?

Comment: [the "Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number)#The_Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy)

Comment: @user7983964 The `select` statement in an `exists` subquery is a little funny. The statement requires a _select list_, but it is ignored since there is no use for any value(s) returned by the `select`. You can use `NULL`, `1 / 0` or even `30 / -3 / 5` and get the same result. I use `42` to show that I pondered the value and chose The Answer as Martin Smith already explained. (Try `select 30 / -3 / 5;` for a laugh.)

Comment: HABO you mean select NULL instead of 42 `select 42 from YourTableOData as iYTOD` to select NULL from YourTableOData as iYTOD`?

Comment: @user7983964 Yes. Try it.

Comment: Yes Select NULL also work which one do you recommend? :)

Comment: @user7983964 You can go wild and use `*` just to annoy the people who insist that `select *` is _always_ evil. I'll stick with `42`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY PaymentID) >= 2 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS M
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Thank you! It works but it returns Y if a single row, does it only check multiple occurrence? it also return `    1456789     1398        4587934     N` for this row because it only one row if multiple Payment ID it seems like working for me, how can i fix that?